# JPA Logging Level on Glassfish v3 Server

Tags: jpa, glassfish-3

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
```

How can I setup the logging level by server. I want to see Level.FINE on my development server. But of course only Level.WARNING on the productive server.

If I put the line above into the persistence.xml then it is automatically setup on both machines. I must remember to switch it off by hand. And that's of course dangerous.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please have a look here, this works fine for me:

[Other Question of me][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047333/logging-level-on-glassfish-3-jpa-eclipselink

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can refer [EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging)

> Note: Setting eclipselink.logging.level to FINE is not sufficient (as of EclipseLink 2.4.0 - Juno), you have to set eclipselink.logging.level.sql to FINE.

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have been struggling with this myself.  What I have discovered is that on GlassFish (at leas on 3.1.2) you edit the logging.properties file from the GlassFish domains/*domain*/config directory.

Locate the org.eclipse.persistence.session.level entry and change it as follows:

```
org.eclipse.persistence.session.level=FINE
```

In addition to this, I have found I need to add these two entries:

```
org.eclipse.persistence.level = FINE
org.eclipse.persistence.sql.level = FINE
```

When editing the logging.properties file like this, there is no need to add anything to the persistence.xml file regarding logging, and it will satisfy your requirements above.

***NOTE**: I have not yet managed to get the eclipselink.logging.parameter=true to work in the persistence.xml (it is not assignable in the logging.properties). So the SQL logging works, just not with the full bindings dump.*

Comment: Does anyone know if these work with newer versions of Glassfish and EclipseLink? They seem not to work with Payara Server 183 and EclipseLink 2.7.3 - at least not without additional configuration (maybe this property **eclipselink.logging.logger** needs to be set somewhere to an appropriate value?).

Answer (score 0):

I added these lines into the logging.properties file and it works without adding it to the persistence.xml. So it is server depended now.

```
eclipselink.logging.level=FINE
eclipselink.logging.level.sql=FINE
eclipselink.logging.parameters=true
```