# Logging Level on Glassfish-3 JPA Eclipselink

Tags: jpa, logging, glassfish-3

How do I setup a EAR and a Glassfish Server that it shows FINE level on the development server but the same ear shows INFO level on the productive machines?

In the moment I change config in the persistence.xml every time i deploy onto the productive machines. 
But s.t. i forget and the machine starts flooding the log files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must put in the

```
    <jvm-options>-Declipselink.logging.level=FINE</jvm-options>
```

into your config.xml java-config tag on your development machine.

And do NOT put in the logging level property into the persistence.xml.

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the EclipseLink log level using System properties (or you could set the log level in code using a SessionCustomizer).

Comment: I would just like to mention that it is important to **remove any logging related configuration** from **persistence.xml** in order for the System Properties to work.
In my case, I set up the logging configuration for EclipseLink in the application server (Payara) in the System Properties - with different levels for production, dev and local machines.